# Sample code of aleaGPU is not working in VB

Tags: vb.net, action, sample, aleagpu

**C# code:**

```cs
    [GpuManaged, Test]
    public static void ActionFactoryWithClosure2()
    {

        var MyGPU = Gpu.Get(0);
        var arg1 = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).ToArray();
        var arg2 = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).ToArray();
        var result = new int[Length];

        Func<int[], Action<int>> opFactory = res => i =>
        {
            res[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i];
        };

        MyGPU.For(0, arg1.Length, opFactory(result));
    }
```

**VB.NET code:**

```vb
    <GpuManaged>
    Public Shared Function GPU_TEST_VB_20170920()

        Dim MyGPU As Alea.Gpu = Gpu.Default

        Dim arg1 = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).ToArray()
        Dim arg2 = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).ToArray()
        Dim result = New Integer(Length - 1) {}
        Dim expected = New Integer(Length - 1) {}

        Dim opFactory As Func(Of Integer(), Action(Of Integer)) = Function(res) Function(i)
                                                                                    res(i) = arg1(i) + arg2(i)
                                                                                End Function


        Dim op As Action(Of Integer) = Function(i) InlineAssignHelper(result(i), arg1(i) + arg2(i))
        Dim op2 As Action(Of Integer) = Sub(i)
                                            result(i) = arg1(i) + arg2(i)
                                        End Sub

        MyGPU.[For](0, result.Length, Function(i) InlineAssignHelper(result(i), arg1(i) + arg2(i))) 'Error : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
        MyGPU.For(0, arg1.Length, opFactory(result)) 'Error : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
        MyGPU.For(0, arg1.Length, op) 'Error : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
        MyGPU.For(0, arg1.Length, op2) 'Error : Cannot get field ""$VB$Local_result. Possible reasons: -> Static field Is Not supported."

End Sub
```

In case of C#, I can run sample code, but in VB, I Got error message (please see above code lines)
What Should I Do

Same condition : VS 2017, Windows 10, AleaGPU 3.0.3

Comment: hi ice, this parallel for doesn't work in VB yet, (if you check the file, the test is ignored), in vb, currently you cannot use delegate, you can only code a static kernel like the first example in that file. That is why we say vb has some issue.

Comment: Ok. As you said "you can only code a static kernel like the first example in that file."

UsingKernel Method is working.  
UsingFor Method is now working.

System.Exception: ... (Maybe KeyNotFoundException. There is no Key in Dictionary)

Source location stack:

-> at MyTest.TransformTest_AleaGPU+_Closure$__3-0.[Void _Lambda$__R1(Int32)]

'
I will use kernel method.
Thank You Very Much.